# boost asio - connect using an ip address

Tags: boost-asio

I want to connect to a server socket specified by a destination ip address and port number.

boost::asio::connect seems it does not allow to use this. I have ip destination as a unsigned int value.

**Update:** I am able to do

```
ba::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint( ba::ip::address(ba::ip::address_v4(req.IpDst())), ntohs(req.Port()));
```

But how can I use endpoint with connect ?

Comment: Have a look at the constructor for basic_endpoint http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_endpoint/basic_endpoint/overload2.html

Comment: @mark thanks for pointing that out I've just discovered that myself. But how can I use endpoint with connect ? Only saw it in use with resolver iterator...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to use:

```
socket.connect(endpoint);
```