# Using an ip address instead of a url in asio

Tags: url, visual-c++, ip-address, boost-asio

I am using Boost::ASIO version 1.52.0 on Windows with SSL version C on a test machine running Win 8 with Visual Studio 2008 code in VC++.

I have some code that successfully connects to a TCP server with a given URL:

```
// Create the resolver and query objects to resolve the host name in serverPath to an ip address.
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(*IOService);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(serverPath, port);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator EndpointIterator = resolver.resolve(query);
// Set up an SSL context.
boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(*IOService, boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv1_client);
// Specify to not verify the server certificiate right now.
ctx.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::context::verify_none);
// Init the socket object used to initially communicate with the server.
pSocket = new boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>(*IOService, ctx);
//
// The thread we are on now, is most likely the user interface thread.  Create a thread to handle all incoming socket work messages.
// This thread is created for each connection to a server.
if (!RcvThreadCreated)
{
   WorkerThreads.create_thread(boost::bind(&SSLSocket::RcvWorkerThread, this));
   RcvThreadCreated = true;
   WorkerThreads.create_thread(boost::bind(&SSLSocket::SendWorkerThread, this));
}
// Try to connect to the server.  Note - add timeout logic at some point.
boost::asio::async_connect(pSocket->lowest_layer(), EndpointIterator,
   boost::bind(&SSLSocket::HandleConnect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

Based upon some research, the above code that resolves the IP address can not be used if an IP address is substituted for the URL in serverPath.  It looks like the right approach is to create an endpoint like this:

```
const boost::asio::ip::address IP(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(serverPath));
int iport = atoi(port.c_str());
boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint EP(IP, iport);
```

This part seems to compile ok.  But, later on in the async_connect method:

```
// Try to connect to the server.  Note - add timeout logic at some point.
boost::asio::async_connect(pSocket->lowest_layer(), EP,
boost::bind(&SSLSocket::HandleConnect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

it generates an error.  I'm guessing that the async_connect method wants to see an iterator for the 2nd argument.  But, I'm not sure how to create one.

According to the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040424/boost-asio-connect-using-an-ip-address), the answer suggests that the connect method on the socket object can be used.  But, when I try doing that:

```
pSocket->connect(EP);
```

The compiler gives an error - error C2039:

```
'connect' : is not a member of 'boost::asio::ssl::stream<Stream>'
```

So, can someone please show some simple code that provides a way to connect to a server with an IP address instead of a URL?

If that is not possible, then is there a way to do a reverse lookup from the IP address to get the URL?

Comment: it's not clear to me where your compilation failure is, can you coalesce your snippets into a single code block example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your async_connect() line of code is not compiling because you are passing the member function pointer without binding an instance to it.  You've bound a member function properly in other places in your code so I think it's just an oversight.  The correct line would be something like:

```
pSocket->next_layer().async_connect(
    EP,
    boost::bind(&SSLSocket::HandleConnect, this, boost::asio::placeholder::error));
```

As for your original issue, getting endpoints for IP addresses, using the ip::tcp::resolver on an IP address query works fine so you shouldn't have to have separate code paths for names and addresses.  Using lowest_layer() on the ssl::stream to get access to the underlying ip::tcp::socket is the correct way to access connect() and async_connect().

Aside from creating the ssl::stream with the ssl::context and using async_handshake() after the connection is established, your SSL code should look nearly identical to your TCP code.  You can use lowest_layer() in your TCP code, too (it just returns itself), which can emphasize the similarities.

I don't guarantee this code compiles because I simplified it from working code, but if you do async_resolve(), your resolve handler method will look something like (`sp_` is a socket/stream pointer):

```
void Pimpl::handleResolve(
  const boost::system::error_code& ec,
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpointIterator) {
  if (ec) {
    // error handling here
    return;      
  }
  sp_->lowest_layer().async_connect( 
     *endpointIterator,
     boost::bind(&Pimpl::handleConnect, this, endpointIterator, boost::asio::placeholder::error));
}
```

Then your connect handler will look like (this tries endpoints until it gets one that works or there aren't any more):

```
void Pimpl::handleConnect(
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpointIterator,
  const boost::system::error_code& ec) {
  if (!ec) {
    sp_->async_handshake(
      boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client,
      boost::bind(&Pimpl::handleHandshake, this, boost::asio::placeholder::error));
  }
  else if (++endpointIterator != boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator()) {
    // Try connecting to the next endpoint.
    sp_->lowest_layer().close();
    sp_->lowest_layer().async_connect(
      *endpointIterator,
      boost::bind(&Pimpl::handleConnect, this, endpointIterator, boost::asio::placeholder::error));
  }
  else {
    // error handling here
  }
}
```

The only line that makes this specific to a ssl::stream pointer and not a ip::tcp::socket pointer is the async_handshake() call.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try it out when I get a spare moment.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around to the problem.  I am using the ssl::stream class as the socket object, and the reason for the error is because it does not have a connect method.  However, it does have a next_layer() method which returns an object which can call the connect or async_connect method.  I had problems getting async_connect to compile, but the connect method works.  I then do a call to my HandleConnect method afterwards like so:

```
boost::system::error_code EC;
pSocket->next_layer().connect(EP, EC);
HandleConnect(EC);
```

In answer to @SamMiller request for the code, it is given below.  I still would like to know how to create an iterator for the endpoint for the boost::asio::async_connect call as well as how to call the async_connect method of the next_layer object.

```
void SSLSocket::Connect(SSLSocket* psSLS, const string& serverPath, string& port)
{
   // Connects to the server.
   // serverPath - specifies the path to the server.  Can be either an ip address or url.
   // port - port server is listening on.
   //
   try
   {
      Locking CodeLock(SocketLock); // Single thread the code.
      // If the user has tried to connect before, then make sure everything is clean before trying to do so again.
      if (pSocket)
      {
         delete pSocket;
         pSocket = 0;
      }                                                                                                  
      // If serverPath is a URL, then resolve the address.
      if ((serverPath[0] < '0') || (serverPath[0] > '9')) // Assumes that the first char of the server path is not a number when resolving to an ip addr.
      {
         // Create the resolver and query objects to resolve the host name in serverPath to an ip address.
         boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(*IOService);
         boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(serverPath, port);
         boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator EndpointIterator = resolver.resolve(query);
         // Set up an SSL context.
         boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(*IOService, boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv1_client);
         // Specify to not verify the server certificiate right now.
         ctx.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::context::verify_none);
         // Init the socket object used to initially communicate with the server.
         pSocket = new boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>(*IOService, ctx);
         //
         // The thread we are on now, is most likely the user interface thread.  Create a thread to handle all incoming socket work messages.
         // This thread is created for each connection to a server.
         if (!RcvThreadCreated)
         {
            WorkerThreads.create_thread(boost::bind(&SSLSocket::RcvWorkerThread, this));
            RcvThreadCreated = true;
            WorkerThreads.create_thread(boost::bind(&SSLSocket::SendWorkerThread, this));
         }
         // Try to connect to the server.  Note - add timeout logic at some point.
         boost::asio::async_connect(pSocket->lowest_layer(), EndpointIterator,
            boost::bind(&SSLSocket::HandleConnect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
      }
      else
      {
         // serverPath is an ip address, so try to connect using that.
         //
         // Create an endpoint with the specified ip address.
         const boost::asio::ip::address IP(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(serverPath));
         int iport = atoi(port.c_str());
         const boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint EP(IP, iport);
         // Set up an SSL context.
         boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(*IOService, boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv1_client);
         // Specify to not verify the server certificiate right now.
         ctx.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::context::verify_none);
         // Init the socket object used to initially communicate with the server.
         pSocket = new boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>(*IOService, ctx);
         //
         // The thread we are on now, is most likely the user interface thread.  Create a thread to handle all incoming socket work messages.
         // This thread is created for each connection to a server.
         if (!RcvThreadCreated)
         {
            WorkerThreads.create_thread(boost::bind(&SSLSocket::RcvWorkerThread, this));
            RcvThreadCreated = true;
            WorkerThreads.create_thread(boost::bind(&SSLSocket::SendWorkerThread, this));
         }
         // Try to connect to the server.  Note - add timeout logic at some point.
         // pSocket->next_layer().async_connect(EP, &SSLSocket::HandleConnect);
         boost::system::error_code EC;
         pSocket->next_layer().connect(EP, EC);
         if (EC)
         {
            // Log an error.  This worker thread should exit gracefully after this.
            stringstream ss;
            ss << "SSLSocket::Connect: connect failed to " << sClientIp << " : " << uiClientPort << ".  Error: " << EC.message() + ".\n";
            Log.LogString(ss.str(), LogError);
         }
         HandleConnect(EC);
      }
   }
   catch (std::exception& e)
   {
      stringstream ss;
      ss << "SSLSocket::Connect: threw an error - " << e.what() << ".\n";
      Log.LogString(ss.str(), LogError);
      Stop();
   }
}
```

This is the error that is generated when the following line:

```
pSocket->next_layer().async_connect(EP, &SSLSocket::HandleConnect); // Does not compile
```

is substituted for:

```
boost::system::error_code EC;
pSocket->next_layer().connect(EP, EC); // Compiles and works properly.
```

Error Message:

```
1>c:\boost_1_52_0\boost\asio\basic_socket.hpp(706) : error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
1>        c:\users\bob\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\attackpoker1\win32client\sslsockets\sslsocket.cpp(114) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::asio::basic_socket<Protocol,SocketService>::async_connect<void(__thiscall SSLSocket::* )(const boost::system::error_code &)>(const boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<InternetProtocol> &,const ConnectHandler &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Protocol=boost::asio::ip::tcp,
1>            SocketService=boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>,
1>            InternetProtocol=boost::asio::ip::tcp,
1>            ConnectHandler=void (__thiscall SSLSocket::* )(const boost::system::error_code &)
1>        ]
```